# Circular Dependency error in android studio while building project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have to build a single application by combining two applications. The two applications are 'app' and 'case'. I added 'case' to 'app' as a library successfully. Now I want to use some classes of 'app' in 'case'. How should i do that?
I added 'app' to 'case' in dependencies as 
        compile project (':app')

but it shows this error

Error:Circular reference between projects: :app-> :case-> :app

Please help .

Comment: You can't do it in this way. You have to create a library with the common code used by both (app and library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an android library project that the two can share that contains the code and resources common to both. Having an app depend on another app seems like bad news even if there wasn't a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Sol1:same name(:app) will not add in Android Studio again.

sol2:if the :app name is not there in your Project, Create new Project and import again, it will work

sol3:in settings.gradle file include ':app',':core' add like this.